# D3 v4 how to smooth out panning while dragging a node outside the viewport

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm sort of combining bits and pieces from a couple of demos that I've found out there that have the features I'm looking for.

- https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708
- http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033

I've seen quite a few very impressive demos out there that have a very nice and smooth effects when panning, dragging and whatnot. That being said I just figure that there must be some way to create a nice smooth pan while dragging on any particular node to the outside of whatever view it's within as well.

Here's what I've got so far. Just click on either of the circles and drag it to outside of the result viewport. As your cursor gets within 20px of the edge you should then see the panning effect kick in.

- https://jsfiddle.net/h3z6q2bw/

The fiddle is working decently thus far, but there are a few issues that I'm having with the current script.

- The demos are using D3 v3 and I am attempting to build out my script using DC v4. It's quite possible that I'm not utilizing all the nice new features of v4 to create the desired effect of the nice smooth drag+pan.
- When dragging outside the window the object being dragged does not stay with your cursor unless the cursor keeps moving.
- When releasing a drag outside the window, or dragging the object outside the window and back in again there is a noticeable jump in the viewport.
- Lastly is just smoothness. Seems like things could be smoother.

I think most the tweaking will need to be done within the following functions (maybe??).

```
function dragMove(){}
function pan(){}
```

Not sure if any or all of these can be fixed, but I was hoping to get a few comments or suggestions as to anything I could try to tweak this script into better shape. Thanks!